@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) is not working with jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider
I have defined below:
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private List<TabInfoFilterItem> filterItems;

and getTabInfoFilterDAO method return:
public TabInfoFilter getFilter {
final List<TabInfoFilter> results = query.getResultList();

      if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(results))
      {
         return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
      }

      return results;
}

@GET
@Path("/formular/{formularId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Collection<TabInfoFilter> getFilters(@PathParam("formularId") final int formularId)
   {
      return getTabInfoFilterDAO().getFilters(mandant, userId, userId, formularId);
   }

But I always receive error below if result have empty list:
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.Collections$EmptyList, genericType=java.util.Collection

I'm using java 21 and jackson 2.18.0
The code work well with javax. The result should return []
